# concat() function can't return full string (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a function and return `CONCAT(arguments)`. My problem is this function can't return a full string. Instead, it only returns first letter of the string. Here is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[formatDateTime]
(@_date SMALLDATETIME, @type VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @_year VARCHAR(4);
    DECLARE @_month VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE @_week VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE @_day VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE @_hour VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE @_minute VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE @_quarter VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @_half VARCHAR(1);
    IF @type = 'minutekey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        SET @_month = CAST(DATEPART(month, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        SET @_day = CAST(DATEPART(day, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        SET @_hour = CAST(DATEPART(hour, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        SET @_minute = CAST(DATEPART(minute, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        RETURN CONCAT(@_hour, ' giờ ', @_minute, ' phút ', 'Ngày ', @_day, '/', @_month, '/', @_year);
    END

    IF @type = 'hourkey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        SET @_month = CAST(DATEPART(month, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        SET @_day = CAST(DATEPART(day, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        SET @_hour = CAST(DATEPART(hour, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        RETURN CONCAT(@_hour, ' giờ ', 'Ngày ', @_day, '/', @_month, '/', @_year);
    END

    IF @type = 'datekey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        SET @_month = CAST(DATEPART(month, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        SET @_day = CAST(DATEPART(day, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        RETURN CONCAT(@_day, '/', @_month, '/', @_year);
    END

    IF @type = 'weekkey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        SET @_week = CAST(DATEPART(week, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        RETURN CONCAT('Tuần ', @_week, ' Năm ', @_year);
    END

    IF @type = 'monthkey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        SET @_month = CAST(DATEPART(month, @_date) AS VARCHAR(2));
        RETURN CONCAT('Tháng ', @_month, ' Năm ', @_year);
    END

    IF @type = 'quarterkey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        SET @_quarter = CAST(DATEPART(quarter, @_date) AS VARCHAR(1));
        RETURN CONCAT('Quí ', @_quarter, ' Năm ', @_year);
    END

    IF @type = 'halfkey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
    DECLARE @m AS INT = DATEPART(month, @_date);
    IF @m <= 6
    BEGIN
          RETURN CONCAT('6 tháng đầu năm ', @_year);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
          RETURN CONCAT('6 tháng cuối năm ', @_year);
    END
    END

    IF @type = 'yearkey'
    BEGIN
        SET @_year = CAST(DATEPART(year, @_date) AS VARCHAR(4));
        RETURN CONCAT('Năm ', @_year);
    END
    RETURN ' ';
END;
```

Then, I call it into a query:

```
SELECT Test.dbo.formatDateTime('2020-09-30 23:10:21', 'datekey')
```

It will return:

[image]

I think `CONCAT()` function doesn't cause it. Because if I write as following (don't create a function), it works fine:

```
DECLARE @_year AS VARCHAR(4) = CAST(DATEPART(year, '2020-09-30 23:10:21') AS VARCHAR(4))
DECLARE @_month AS VARCHAR(2) = CAST(DATEPART(month, '2020-09-30 23:10:21') AS VARCHAR(2))
DECLARE @_day AS VARCHAR(2) = CAST(DATEPART(day, '2020-09-30 23:10:21') AS VARCHAR(2))
SELECT CONCAT(@_day, '/', @_month, '/', @_year)
```

Result:

[image]

What happens with my function? Who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do NOT mix the use of varchar and nvarchar - especially with literals. The first thing to do is force your literals to be unicode by prefixing all those strings with N (e.g., N' giờ '). 
 And really start thinking about your datatypes. Why varchar(1)? There is nothing "variable" about your usage. THINK!

Comment: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bdfd37be6ab50c2c189181d8a1c5d698) says it works. Aside: You could factor out `declare @_year as Char(4) = Cast( Year( @_date ) as Char(4) );` since every format uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I created your function exactly as you specified (literally copy-pasted), and executed it as you specified - the output is exactly what you would expect - 30/9/2020.

Are you sure you are executing the correct function when you are trying it with your query? Is it possible you're using the wrong database, IE, the function you're executing isn't the one you think it is?

On a side note though, I would suggest you look into the different date format functions that already exist in SQL Server, since it feels like you're doing something that is already built-in (I can't tell for sure since I don't have a translation for your words).

See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5993/sql-server-date-and-time-functions-with-examples/ for many examples - I feel like you can probably get what you want from those, in a much cleaner fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use build-in function of SQL Server

```
.
.
.
 IF @type = 'datekey'
    BEGIN
        RETURN FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, @_date), 'd/M/yyyy');
    END
.
.
.
```